# Why isn't the C# inequality operator !==?

Tags: c#, operators

In C#, `==` is used to check equality, whereas `=` is for assignment.

Does this mean that checking for inequality should really be `!==`.

Why isn't this the case? Os it for historical reasons?

The rise of `!=` has seen it establish itself in most SQL variations now too.

Comment: This probably should be asked at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think `!=` kind of makes sense (2 characters, like `==`).  Since there is no "not assignment" operator, it doesn't really overlap with anything either.  Just my opinion (thus not an answer).

Comment: You ought to ask K&R. But they probably copied it too.

Comment: The only reason they use `==` is to prevent ambiguity with the assignment operator. In the case of `!=`, there's no ambiguity so why force programmers to use another character?

Comment: Why not `/=`? That's what ALGOL used. K&R decided to use `!=`. It's just a convention. C++ is based on C, Java is C-like is some ways so it has that same operator, and C# has some roots in C with syntax too.

Comment: C inherited `!=` from its ancestor [B](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/kbman.html).

Comment: Ther is no direct relation with ==, it could have been <> as well.

Comment: I know these are just conventions. Its just that it seems like the logical option would be to use (not)(equality) i.e. !== I can see how this might have been the choice, but then shortened to !=, as there was no conflict with another operator. And it saved some key presses!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C# had a lot of influence from Java and C/C++ both of which use `==` and `!=`.  I imagine they simply chose to stick with the existing predominant pattern instead of reinventing the wheel. Choosing another syntax say `===` for equality and `!===` for inequality would've been a stumbling block for the vast majority of developers they were targeting

Comment: Yeah I agree it would probably have been by consensus to keep things consistent, just wondered if anyone knew if that was the actual reason.

Answer (score 3):

== is just a synonym for Equality, != is just one for inequality. It is just a synonym! It is no logical expression and therefore there is no need to follow any logical rules! It is the same with &=, |=, ^=...

It is not that !!=====.Equals(true), it is just a name ;)